# FragmentActivity which is a supertype of MainActivity can not be accessed

Tags: android, gradle, android-activity, appcompatactivity

When I wanna create a new project in AS I get this error:

**Cannot access 'androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity' which is a supertype of 'com.example.test123.MainActivity'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies**

After that I can not build/rebuild or run my clean new project.
any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got the same issue with my gradle and project build/rebuild,
the solution however is somehow random but i tried to remove the contents of my ".gradle" folder to force my project to download it from scratch.

After doing that in the AS i changed the gradle plugin version to a latest release (ex. alpha x.xx) in File -> Project Structure and rebuild project
and then again reverted back to latest stable release and my project built without any issue.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have the appcompat library in the app's build.gradle file. If it's still not working, try to invalidate caches and restart.

Comment: tnx but not worked

Comment: Invalidate caches worked for me. It makes dependencies to be fetched again and sync project with gradle files to be run. Seems that sync project with gradle files  should be run and it makes sense, that if you change something in your gradle files dependencies, this error vanishes even if you change does nothing like material class with missing class.

Answer (score 1):

In my case this is what worked:
In my build.gradle module dependencies, I changed

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case my laptop don´t connect to internet. I fixed this and worked.